# Estimating probability of having negative value

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I want to estimate the probability of having at least a negative value in a vector.

I have 300 vectors with values from -1 to 1... These vectors should have in reality only positive values from 0 to 1 but sometimes (for unknown reason) there are some negative values...

What I did to estimate this probability is calculated to percentage of negative values in each vector and then I went for the mean of all these percentages.

I want to know if I'm reasoning right or there's a better way to solve the problem...

Comment: That would give the same result as finding the overall proportion of negative vales if all the vectors have the same length

Comment: Thanks for the answer Henry. Is there another method Im missing to solve this ?

Comment: It's not just the count of negative elements that matters, it matters how far below 0 the negative values are. If the actual dist'n of (indep) vector values is UNIF(-.01, 1.01), then  you'd have a little less than 1 negative value in 100. But if it's UNIF(-.1, 1.1),$ then you'd get about 8% negative values.